# Lombok: RequiredArgsConstructor giving error while generating Constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, lombok

It seems that @RequiredArgsConstructor not working in the code below.It throws error when I generate constructor . Why is it?

```
 import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NonNull;
    import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
    /**
     * Login response object containing the JWT
     **/
    @Data
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class LoginResult {
        
        @NonNull
        private  String jwt;
    
        public LoginResult(String jwt) {
            this.jwt = jwt;
        }
    }
```

Dependency added in maven is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

***Error is - Duplicate method LoginResult(String) in type LoginResult***

Comment: because you both manually add it and try to have lombok add it. Exactly as the error message tells you.

Comment: so whats the solution, how can i make parameterized constructor in this case

Comment: you already have one. The problem is you are trying to create/generate what you already have. Just remove the constructor you actually typed and it 'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Lombok's `@RequiredArgsConstructor` which generates a constructor with 1 parameter for each field that requires special handling. In your case `@NonNull` on jwt field is saying `jwt` field needs special handling (a null check basically). Now lombok have added a constructor and even you have added a constructor and hence the error. `Duplicate method LoginResult(String) in type LoginResult`

You can find more infomation about it on the following page https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor. (Adding screenshot in case it changes in future)

[image]

`Solution:`  Remove your constructor and let Lombok do the magic